# Which Timed JSONWebSignature Serializer replacement for itsdangerous is better? pyjwt or authlib

Tags: flask, authlib, pyjwt, itsdangerous

Currently I was using `itsdangerous` to generate timed json web signature as a token for users to auth and resetpassword etc. Here's the code:

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer

class SampleCode:
    def generate_confirmation_token(self, expiration=600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=expiration)
        return s.dumps({'confirm': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    def confirm(self, token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('confirm') != self.id:
            return False
        self.confirmed = True
        db.session.add(self)
        return True
```

And since `TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer` is [deprecated](https://github.com/pallets/itsdangerous/blob/d1c85670cce70d81f9949619434daf8c0b9cd37e/src/itsdangerous/jws.py#L23-L30) and removed in `itsdangerous` `2.1.0` I think I might need to move on to some other libs that provides a JWT/JWS interface.

And here I've got two candidates, which one is better:

- [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: @RobinUphoff, I do wish, If it's possible, don't copy my code. https://github.com/realJustinLee/LiCMS/commit/30437d22c11b09626d60e2d698c2670dcbde962e

Comment: With all respect Justin, but when revising the former code and following pyjwts documentation this is the result. I did not see any code of your project before. If you already found the solution, you could have posted it here...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which library is to be rated as "better" depends very much on the use case.

If you want to keep it short and simple, I would recommend pyjwt. Its easy to set the expiration time, whereas i could not find a suited flag for that option in the authlib JWS documentation. So just change your code as follows:

```
import jwt
import datetime

class SampleCode:
    def generate_confirmation_token(self, expiration=600):
        reset_token = jwt.encode(
            {
                "confirm": self.id,
                "exp": datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
                       + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expiration)
            },
            current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
            algorithm="HS256"
        )
        return reset_token

    def confirm(self, token):
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(
                token,
                current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
                leeway=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10),
                algorithms=["HS256"]
            )
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('confirm') != self.id:
            return False
        self.confirmed = True
        db.session.add(self)
        return True
```

Hope I could help!