# "ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous' - Python Error"

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, itsdangerous

I encountered an ImportError while trying to use the TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer class from the itsdangerous library in my Python project. The error message is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous'

I'm using Python 3.x.
I have confirmed that the itsdangerous library is installed in my virtual environment.
The library is being imported using the correct import statement, but the specific class TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer seems to be causing the issue.

If you've encountered this error before or have insights on how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Timed JSONWebSignature Serializer replacement for itsdangerous is better? pyjwt or authlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292764/which-timed-jsonwebsignature-serializer-replacement-for-itsdangerous-is-better)